# How can I make my text appear in the center of this DIV both vertically and horizontally?

Tags: css

I need to center text vertically and horizontally. Is there a simple way to do this for the following code?

```
<div style="display: block; height: 25px;">
    <span id="ctl_txt" style="background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);">
        Basic
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use the `text-align` property to center the text horizontally, and `line-height` equal to the div height to center inline elements vertically.

```
<div style="display: block; height: 25px; text-align:center; line-height:25px;">
    <span id="ctl_txt" style="background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);">Basic</span>
</div>
```

[Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/Nhhkx/).

Answer (score 7):

Another way to do this, different from @Jose, is to use

`display:table;` and `display:table-cell`

like this

```
div{
    display:table; 
    height:125px;  //JUST FOR SHOW
    width:125px;   //JUST FOR SHOW
}

span{
    background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Then `vertical-align:middle;` and `text-align:center;` do the work.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/unfwL/1/

Comment: True @anglimass.  However, since the OP did not mention browser restrictions, I thought he could see this alternate approach ;-)